# Linq query doesn't return a result from object within another object

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use Linq to return a property of an object within an object. This is a simplified version of the program that demonstrates the behaviour.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Associate
        {
            public string AssocType { get; set; }
            public Contact contact { get; set; }
            public Associate(string assocType)
            {
                AssocType = assocType;
                //contact = new Contact("Contact 1", 1234);
                //contact2 = new Contact("Contact 2", 23456);
            }
        }
        public class Contact
        {
            string v1;
            int v2;
            public Contact(string v1, int v2) { this.v1 = v1; this.v2 = v2; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int ID { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Associate assoc1 = new Associate("Type1");
            assoc1.contact = new Contact("Contact 1", 9876);
            Associate assoc2 = new Associate("Type2");
            assoc2.contact = new Contact("Contact 2", 1234);
            List<Associate> aList = new List<Associate>
            {
                assoc1,assoc2
            };
            var contactname = aList
                .Where(s => s.AssocType == "Type1")
                .Select(s => s.contact.Name)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            Console.Write(contactname);
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

The `contactname` variable is coming up as null but should return `Contact 1` as a string. I have checked in the debugger and all the objects are set correctly and have the appropriate values. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried the below linq syntax (in place of the `var contact name = aList...` part but I don't think it's correct as it won't compile due to `Type inference failed`.

```
        var name = from Associate in aList
                   from Contact in Associate
                   where Associate.AssocType == "Type1"
                   select Contact.Name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Contact` class, you're never setting the `Name` property so when you execute the below pipeline:

```
var contactname = aList.Where(s => s.AssocType == "Type1")
                       .Select(s => s.contact.Name)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

it's returning `null` (not to be confused with the `null` returned by `FirstOrDefault`, this is the `null` value of the `Name` property as it's never been set ).

You can prove this with:

```
var count = aList.Count(s => s.AssocType == "Type1" && s.contact.Name == null);
Console.Write(count); // prints  --> 1
```

So either, you meant:

```
var contactname = aList.Where(s => s.AssocType == "Type1")
                       .Select(s => s.contact.v1) // note the change
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

assuming `v1` is public.

or you'll explicitly need to populate the `Name` property of the `Contact` object sometime before the above pipeline.

---

Finally, for completeness if you want the query syntax then do:

```
var result = (from a in aList
              where a.AssocType == "Type1"
              select a.contact.Name)
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That's it - I think my constructor confused me. Had to make the properties (v1, v2) public as well for them to be accessible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Contact name is `null` because you have not initialised anywhere.

> public Contact(string v1, int v2) { this.v1 = v1; this.v2 = v2; }

Either this should be

```
public Contact(string v1, int v2) { Name = v1; ID = v2; }
```

Or

> public string Name { get; set; }

This should be (same for ID too)

```
public string Name { get { return v1; } }
```